# Git status not detecting changes, but "git update-index --really-refresh" does

Tags: git

I have 3 folders in my project. 2 of them detect changes with `git status`, but the third one, `Server/`, doesn't.

`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Server/` returns

`Ignoring path Server/`

Strangely enough,

`git update-index --assume-unchanged Server/`  returns

`Ignoring path Server/` as well.

After git status, changes still don't display. However, running `git update-index --really-refresh` shows them; how can I make `git status` show them like normal?

Answer (score 1):

A path that *ends* with `/`, like `Server/`, can never name a *file* in the index.  Such a path names a directory (or folder, if you prefer that term).

Unlike many user-oriented commands, `git update-index` is a pretty basic plumbing command and has no ability to operate on all files within a directory just by naming the directory.  So if you do give it the name of a directory—even one that does not exist—it just complains as above:

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged abcdefg/
Ignoring path abcdefg/
```

despite a total lack of `abcdefg/` files, or even an `abcdefg` directory:

```
$ file abcdefg/
abcdefg/: cannot open `abcdefg/' (No such file or directory)
```

If you do have files within `Server/` and wish to set these index flags on the entries for these files that do currently exist in the index, you must name each such file individually:

```
$ git ls-files --stage builtin/
100644 dd18e5c9b67038307401e8d33970d5c424c03cb7 0       builtin/add.c
100644 761cac39e02a7f45dd7f95f05d31e0ad373be214 0       builtin/am.c
100644 da413ae0d178b53d6b1e6c193577c23923255245 0       builtin/annotate.c
100644 3f099b960565ff2944209ba514ea7274dad852f5 0       builtin/apply.c
[many more lines, snipped]
```

To set or clear the assume-unchanged flag on each of these index entries, you (or I) would have to invoke `git update-index` once for each such file.  There are 112 such files, so that requires 112 calls to `git update-index`.

(Using `git update-index` directly this often is almost always a sign that you're doing something wrong.  If you have set many assume-unchanged flags, that was probably the real mistake; you'll have to unset them all individually to fix it.  I did write my own [Python script](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged) to deal with this sort of thing, partly as an experiment and partly when I was dealing with a bad situation where I was setting and clearing flags often.  The overall situation is now rectified but I still have the script.)